# Is the gravity between objects other than celestials observable?

Tags: gravity, observables

I've always read that all matter has gravity. But, can we observe it? I mean, The Earth pulls us but what about small daily objects?

For example, if we release 2 small objects in space, do they get closer?

My point of asking this question is that, maybe the gravity comes from the rotation of the Earth, not from its mass. I know I'm wrong by saying that but I want to know about the experiment and observation (aka proof) of that concept.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/62124/2451

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71940/understanding-the-different-kinds-of-mass-in-gravity/71945#71945 and, in particular, the Eotvos experiment

Comment: Have you heard about the Cavendish experiment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many experiments, the most famous of them is probably the Cavendish experiment, done in 18th century by a British scientist.

I believe it was the first one to measure the force acting between two masses in a laboratory. He calculated the attraction between two lead spheres.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment

So, I believe 'yes' is the answer to your question.